# AWS Stepfunction: Substring from input

Tags: substring, aws-step-functions

As a general question is it possible do a substring function within step functions?

I receive the following event:

```json
          {
              "input": {
                "version": "0",
                "id": "d9c5fec0-d08d-6abd-4ea5-0107fbbce47d",
                "detail-type": "EBS Multi-Volume Snapshots Completion Status",
                "source": "aws.ec2",
                "account": "12345678",
                "time": "2021-11-12T12:08:16Z",
                "region": "us-east-1",
                "resources": [
                  "arn:aws:ec2::us-east-1:snapshot/snap-0a98c2a42ee266123"
                ]
              }
            }
```

but need the snapshot id as input to DescribeInstances, therefore I need to extract `snap-0a98c2a42ee266123` from `arn:aws:ec2::us-east-1:snapshot/snap-0a98c2a42ee266123`

Is there any simple way to do this within step functions?. That is to say without having to pass it to a lambda or something equally convoluted?

Answer (score 1):

This has recently become possible with the addition of new [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html). `ArrayGetItem` gets an item by its index.  `StringSplit` splits a string at a delimeter.  Use a `Pass` state to extract the snapshot name from the resource ARN:

```json
{
  "StartAt": "ExtractSnapshotName",
  "States": {
    "ExtractSnapshotName": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "input.$": "$.input",
        "snapshotName.$":  "States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit(States.ArrayGetItem($.input.resources,0), '/'),1)"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

output:

```json
{
  "input": {
    "version": "0",
    "id": "d9c5fec0-d08d-6abd-4ea5-0107fbbce47d",
    "detail-type": "EBS Multi-Volume Snapshots Completion Status",
    "source": "aws.ec2",
    "account": "12345678",
    "time": "2021-11-12T12:08:16Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [
      "arn:aws:ec2::us-east-1:snapshot/snap-0a98c2a42ee266123"
    ]
  },
  "snapshotName": "snap-0a98c2a42ee266123"
}
```